# How to verify exception thrown using StepVerifier in project reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

```
    def expectError() {

        StepVerifier.create(readDB())
                    .expectError(RuntimeException.class)
                    .verify();
    }

     private Mono<String> readDB() {
//        try {
            return Mono.just(externalService.get())
                    .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.error(throwable));

//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            return Mono.error(e);
//        }
    }
```

unable to make it work if externalService.get throws Exception instead of return Mono.error. Is is always recommended to transform to Mono/Flow using try catch or is there any better way to verify such thrown exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, if the user-provided code that throws an exception is provided as a lambda, exceptions can be translated to `onError`. But here you're directly throwing in the main thread, so that cannot happen

Comment: so my understanding is if implementation is under our control,  never throw exception like that especially in main thread, and if we are consuming external service which can throws the exceptions, always try/catch and translate to onError so that It can continue to flow on the pipeline. right?

Comment: here you're not even creating a Flux or mono, the exception is thrown before there is a chance to do that

Comment: I modified the snippet little bit to reflect the issue. but as you suggested in answer, if I manage to call externalService through lambda as follows, I find it works too. so this is recommended solution right?                                               
return Mono.just("hello")                                 
      .map(s -> get())
      .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.error(throwable));

Comment: to some extent. you can avoid the weird `just`+`map` by using `Mono.fromCallable`. But there's a potential antipattern here if the `get()` method is blocking, see https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: (NB: use the `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` as suggested in the FAQ only if on Reactor-Core >= 3.3.3.RELEASE. otherwise use `Schedulers.elastic()`)